# Huggingface transformers error: "from transformers.trainer_utils import get_last_checkpoint,is_main_process"

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

I am using Google Colab and trying to use [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers). first, I installed `trasnformers` using `pip`, and it installed successfully but I was still unable to import the following functions

```py
from transformers.trainer_utils import get_last_checkpoint,is_main_process
```

Next I tried to install `Transformers` from source in a virtual environment. I installed it successfully, but was still getting the same error as shown below.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-d42272f1d6ac> in <module>()
----> 1 from transformers.trainer_utils import get_last_checkpoint,is_main_process

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.trainer_utils'
```

Comment: Which version have you installed (`import transformers`, `transformers.__version__`)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue fixed after installing "master" version from source. "pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers"

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> The issue fixed after installing "master" version from source as shown
> below
>
> ```
> pip install git+github.com/huggingface/transformers
> ```